# Intellij 15.0.5 issue with SBT and Scala project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to set up IntelliJ for my Scala development after hearing how much better it is compared to alternatives. But I can't seem to run anything. The problems I'm facing are as follows:

1. As soon as the project is created, the console shows SBT failures
2. My build.sbt file shows red wiggles (compile time errors)
3. The confusing part is that opening the "SBT Console" view from within the IDE works fine.

The error trace is something along the lines of:

```
[info] Loading project definition from D:\workspaces\intellij\scala\untitled\project
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect
[error] (*:update) java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Would anyone please know what can cause this? I have tried deleting the project and creating a new one but the problem still persists.

**UPDATE**

Just had a look at `.sbt\boot\update.log` and something seems fishy. Is it just me or the `sbt.ivy.home` is completely borked?

```
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.osgi.obr.OBRResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define glob matcher: org.apache.ivy.plugins.matcher.GlobPatternMatcher was not found.
setting 'jline.esc.timeout' to '0'
setting 'sbt.ivy.home' to 'D:\software\installed\sbt\.ivy2 -Divy.home=D:\software\installed\sbt\.ivy2'
setting 'java.runtime.name' to 'Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment'
```

Comment: 1. Did you install scala support in plugins section? 2. Did you specify scala sdk in project settings? Check Project settings

Comment: I would investigate that IOException. Something is wrong with the file system where your project is stored.

Comment: @AlexanderKondaurov: Yes to everything, can't see anything wrong with the project settings :(

Comment: @rspencer: The project path looks fine (no special chars and so on). Maybe you can please suggest some way of debugging this issue?

Comment: That error didn't show up for no reason. Is the project on the D: drive and not the C: drive? Do all the directories in the path shown exist? You might want to try the `last *:update` command to see more on the error

Comment: @sasuke, i'm not windows user, i use os x and ubuntu for developing and haven't faced problem like your

Comment: @rspencer: Updated the post with more information. The ivy home path seems messed up which is why the `IOException`. Now the question is what could cause that to be the case...

Comment: The listing you added shows ''D:\software\installed\sbt\.ivy2" as your Ivy Home directory. Does that directory exist and have content? If so, then your Ivy Home is fine. Not sure what is with the "impossible to define" messages but the OBRResolver is something from OSGi that Ivy uses to locate files based on URLs.

Comment: @rspencer: The listing shows the `sbt.ivy.home` as `'D:\software\installed\sbt\.ivy2 -Divy.home=D:\software\installed\sbt\.ivy2'`. Isn't that wrong though? Why would the home have a path + `-D` and the path again?

Comment: @sasuke - yes, looks wrong to me too, like the definition of ivy.home includes the path and the command line option to set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally managed to hunt down the root cause. The errors were due to rogue environment variables set in my profile related to SBT (specifically `SBT_OPTS`). Once I deleted all of them and started with a clean slate, things started working on expected.